# Open File in eclipse programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I need to open up a file in eclipse from another program for example just from a bash in Linux or the Command prompt in Windows.

Something like `eclipse.exe myfile.js`

which works, but I don't want it to start another eclipse instance for each file but open the file in the current eclipse instance if one exists.

Is there any chance of opening a file in that way?

Comment: Eclipse does not have anything to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open file in eclipse from command line
Check the wiki page . [eclipse open file feature](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/OpenFileFeature)